# How can you start an application when the user presses a keystroke in Java?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an **Swing application** in Java that I want to open when the user types as specific keystroke, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. It would be better if there isn't an application running in the background tracking all the key events and then showing the window.

Comment: Without a application running in the background it's not possible, because then there is no application that could recognize it. And even when using a background application I think this application can't be done in java, because java wont be able to receive all events from the keyboard when it's not in the foreground (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this but the simplest way is to create a shortcut of that application either on Desktop or in a start menu, right click on the icon and select properties and go to shortcuts and click on the shortcut key textbox. Now select keys from your keyboard and save it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1rQ9.png)

Comment: Is there a way to create the shortcut from inside Java itself?

Comment: I don't think so java could do this, u can search for installers where you can do such type activities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to do so without a JAVA application already running.
If you wish to use short cuts you will have to use OS related shortcuts

Check out this Stack Exchange [link](https://superuser.com/questions/112981/how-to-create-a-new-keyboard-shortcut-using-the-windows-key) to create a shortcut on Windows OS